# Copy Cells worksheet as label caption onto UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, label, caption, userform

I did come across this answer given by mehow as I was searching for a way to capture cells on a worksheet, and instead of copying them on the same sheet, I was wondering.

Could the code given below be altered in such a way I could for example copy the cells
and paste them as label captions on a UserForm.

```
Sub RangeToArray()
  Dim arr As Variant
  arr = Range("B6:H14").Value
  Dim r As Long, c As Long
  Dim i, j

  r = 16
  c = 2

  For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
      Cells(r, c) = arr(i, j)
      c = c + 1
    Next j
    c = 2
    r = r + 1
  Next i
End Sub
```

I figured out a way the have an array fill labels but they only copy one colum down all the way instead of given rows AND colums.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question, but this may solve the general problem

Create a UserForm (we'll call it frmOne)

Create a function in the form of:

```
Public Sub updateLabel1(value as String)
      Label1.Caption = String
End Sub
```

If you need more of these functions, you could create one for each label

Then in your function given, just add a line:

```
Call frmOne.updateLabel1(arr(i,j))
```

Let me know if you have questions!

Comment: I did follow up your advice, however I'am not able to call the sub on frmOne.

Comment: Right. That makes sense.. It's because I declared the Sub to be Private. Please see the edit

Comment: I was looking for a way to pupulate multiple labels on a UserForm.

Comment: I was looking for a way to pupulate multiple labels on a UserForm.
I came across the camera option of Excel and added it to the Quick Access Toolbar. The "picture" is pasted on the Userform and changes realtime with the worksheet.

The only thing left now is to find a way the conditionally format the value to the left and the columnheaders of the value found.

Maybe I have to  start a new question for that one.